# VSTS Group Variables not able to use through Powershell task

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I crated VSTS Group Variables with link with secrets from Azure Key Vault it contains SSH key.

As one of my Build task I am using Powershell task where I am passing the argument

```
-keyname $(vsts-ssh)
```

To see if it is retrieving the key propel I am printing it in powershell

```
Param(
[string] $keyname
)

Write-Host "hi there"
Write-Host $keyname
```

But the output is

> hi there
>
> -----BEGIN

The out put has only first few words and that is it.

am i doing something wrong on how I am using the variable

Answer (score 2):

To troubleshot the issue, please check with below aspects:

#### 1.   Check if the vault secret has been added correctly in vriable group

In your variable group, make sure the vault sccret `vsts-ssh` has been added as variable in variable group (as the vault sccret `sqlpassword` in below example).

[image]

#### 2.   Check if the variable group has been linked to your build definition

In your build definition, please check if the variable group with the secret `vsts-ssh` (as the vault sccret `sqlpassword` in my example) has been linked.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Pass the argument like this:

```
-keyname "$(vsts-ssh)"
```